# JavaScript function being blocked by office addin

Tags: javascript, html

I have an outlook add-in that I have created. In this add-in I am trying to make a button pull some data from a website using APIs.

I was able to do this on with a local test but when I put the code into my add-in nothing happens. It gives an error in the console that says `Tracking Prevention blocked access to storage for https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/en-us/outlook_strings.js.` but when I commented out my javascript code, that error still came up. So I don't know why my code is being blocked.

Picture of problem:
[image]

On my local computer it works no problem:
[image]

Here is my code:
javascript:

```
function freshdesktickets() {
    Office.onReady((info) => {
//   window.parent.location.reload()
  const url = "https://alloysystems.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets";
fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        // needed to base64 encode my key with ":x" at the end of the api key then I used that for the authorization header.
    "authorization": "Basic YOUWILLNEVERGETMYAPIKEYLOL"
    }
})
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {let text = "";
    const output = document.querySelector('span.ms-font-m');
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let text = "Subject: " + JSON.stringify(data[i].subject) + "<br>"+
        "CC Emails: " + JSON.stringify(data[i].cc_emails).replace("[]","No Emails are CC'd").replace("[","").replace("]","") + "<br>" +
        "Ticket Creation Date: " + JSON.stringify(data[i].created_at) + "<br>" +
        "Ticket Status: " + JSON.stringify(data[i].status).replace("2", "Open").replace("3", "Pending").replace("4", "Resolved").replace("5", "Closed").replace("6", "Waiting On Customer") ;
        let pre = document.createElement('pre');
        
        pre.innerHTML = text;
        pre.style.cssText += 'font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;'

        output.appendChild(pre);
        console.log(pre)
      }
    })})

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ms-PanelExample">
    <script src="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/js/fabric.min.js"></script>
    <button style="margin:1px;" id="get-freshdesk" class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary">
      <span class="ms-Button-label">Freshdesk Tickets</span>
    </button>
  <div class="ms-Panel ms-Panel--xxl">
    <button class="ms-Panel-closeButton ms-PanelAction-close">
      <i class="ms-Panel-closeIcon ms-Icon ms-Icon--Cancel"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="ms-Panel-contentInner">
      <p class="ms-Panel-headerText">Freshdesk Integration</p>
      <div class="ms-Panel-content">
        <span class="ms-font-m">Latest Ticket information</span> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var PanelExamples = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-PanelExample");
  for (var i = 0; i < PanelExamples.length; i++) {
    (function() {
      var PanelExampleButton = PanelExamples[i].querySelector(".ms-Button");
      var PanelExamplePanel = PanelExamples[i].querySelector(".ms-Panel");
      PanelExampleButton.addEventListener("click", function(i) {
        new fabric['Panel'](PanelExamplePanel);
      });
    }());
  }
</script>
```

Result from console:

```
Tracking Prevention blocked access to storage for https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/en-us/outlook_strings.js.
### yet it displays the pre information in the console below because I added console.log(pre)
```

I also tried adding the domains of where the api gets its data but I am still getting the error. I added it to the edge's exclusion list and I also added it to the manifest xml.

[image]

code that was added to the manifest xml to ensure that the api's domain is allow to get some data:

```
  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://freshdesk.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://alloysystems.freshdesk.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->
```

Comment: See this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/tracking-prevention

Comment: I already have my domains in the exclusion list for edge from using that link. Infact, I already read that link before I made the post. I thought maybe edge was blocking my data so I tried to allow it from the tracker exclusion list and I still got the exact same result. However I do thank you for thinking out side the box.

Answer (score 0):

I **think** I figured out the answer. The problem is that I added the javascript to my existing office apps javascript which has `Office.onReady((info) =>` at the top of the script. If I add my javascript to the existing office apps javascript it will fail.

So I made a new javascript file and added that to the html. In the new file I used the javascript code above, then I simply added the script to the head tag and it started working.